# confluent platform vs apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am new to kafka and I am curious about the Confluent platform. It seems that there are not many user stories on the Confluent platform. What are the differences between the Confluent platform and Apache Kafka?

Comment: I don't understand why SO keeps closing such questions just because it is opinion-based.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

"Which one is your favorite" is probably not a question appropriate to this forum since it is very subjective.
I can, however, describe the differences.

Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka, so you will get that in any case. It also includes few things that can make Apache Kafka easier to use:

- Clients in Python, C, C++ and Go. Apache Kafka includes Java client. If you use a different language, Confluent Platform may include a client you can use.
- Connectors - Apache Kafka include a file connector. Confluent adds HDFS, JDBC and Elastic Search connectors.
- REST Proxy - adds a REST API to Apache Kafka, so you can use it in any language or even from your browser
- Schema Registry - if you use Avro, the schema registry will store the Avro schemas for each topic for you and help with schema evolution and compatibility.
- Support - Confluent Platform is supported by Confluent. Apache Kafka on its own is not really supported by anyone (other vendors package it with their own platforms and support their own platforms, just like Confluent supports Kafka in the Confluent Platform).

Comment: Some of the parts of the platform such as ksql can be extracted out to work with vanilla Apache Kafka. So you can always mix and match somewhat later

Comment: IMO, this question isn't about "which one is your favorite". I came across this question because I was curious about the technical differences between them. Seeing that confluent is built off of Apache Kafka for instance is not opinion-based.

Comment: Also, on a side note, the core Kafka part of the Confluent platform is under Apache License 2.0. But, other additional features develop atop it may/not be free. Details are here: https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/

Comment: Confluent platform is free? can we use it for production?