# Why would someone pick apache Kafka instead of Confluent?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm about to start deploying to production a couple of Kafka cluster in 2 different DCs. My main use is for replication using MirrorMaker. To continuously stream/replicate ElasticSearch and Postgres between DCs in order to have a (near) real-time backup and failover.

What I can't get my head around is this simplest question: should I use Confluent or apache Kafka?

I can see that Confluent adds many niceties but what I don't get it: why would someone pick plain Apache Kafka then? I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703338/confluent-platform-vs-apache-kafka/39709900#39709900) and it seems clear: "pick Confluent, has way more stuff".

Answer (score 0):

As answered in linked post, you can add whatever external processes you want to Apache Kafka.

Note: You are not picking **either or**, you are always picking Apache Kafka. Confluent Platform **adds on top of**, similar to Cloudera's Data Platform, as an alternative consideration.

If you want to connect Elasticsearch and Postgres (via JDBC), both of those connectors are Open-Source under the [Confluent Community License](http://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license), so that would be one potential reason for not using Confluent products.

Other reason: Do you *need* the "more stuff"? Are you able to get support from elsewhere? For example, AWS support on MSK or IBM Streams or Azure EventHub are not using Confluent Platform (because it's against the above license)

MirrorMaker and MirrorMaker2 are both under the Apache License, so they have no such usage / redistribution restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> should I use Confluent or apache Kafka?

When deciding on deploying a vanilla Apache or a commercially supported product you should think about the O&M (operation and maintenance) timeline and what you gain and lose. Whatever you choose will be very difficult to replace once in production.

I'll also agree with @OneCricketeer's answer.

> Do you need the "more stuff"?

I work as a professional services consultant with some Apache products. My advice is keep your stack (whatever it is) as simple as possible. So if you don't *need* the additional tools and functionality of Confluent, don't use them. It's how they make the product "sticky" (re: vendor lock-in).

#### Vanilla Apache Kafka

- **Pro** No vendor lock-in or dependencies
- **Pro** Faster updates and feature development
- **Con** No nice dashboards
- **Con** Harder to secure

#### Confluent

- **Pro** Commercial support and professional services available
- **Pro** More stable with fast and easy security patches
- **Pro** Nice dashboard and management tools
- **Pro** Easier to properly secure
- **Con** Expensive
- **Con** Expect vendor lock-in and frequent up-sells

#### My Opinion

If you have money to spare and this will be a critical piece of infrastructure I'd recommend buying through Confluent. If you try to avoid paying for them, you'll have to hire someone (expensive) who knows it anyway and you'll have to deal with the patching nightmare of open source projects.

If this is something you want to kick the tires on, can allow for downtime, or think you'll replace in 2 years, I'd just use the Apache Kafka with one of the open source dashboards.